# Passing per_page values dynamically for each page in Paginator class

Tags: python, django, paginator

how can I pass **per_page_count=[8,10,9,10,10]** to **Paginator** class .

I have a **sorted_query_list** which is passed to **Paginator** class but
 for ***per_page*** value each query can have different **per_page_count**. 
So a list is generated for each query (i.e **per_page_count**) containing number of rows to be shown in each page in sequential manner

So result should have *8 rows for 1st page , 10 rows for 2 , 9 rows for 3 page , 10 rows for 4 page and so on* .

```
per_page_count=[8,10,9,10,10]    
for rows_per_page in per_page_count :
        result = Paginator(sorted_query_list, rows_per_page )
```

^ Obviously this doesn't works !

Note: per_page_count can have different value for different  sorted_query_list

Comment: what if  sum of your list less than total rows?

Comment: This looks like "*bizzarre*" use cases. Why do you need this?

Comment: no ! that won't happen per_page_count is created with some logic that i have not mentioned .It would always be equal to number of rows

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/pagination/#paginator-objects) you cannot do that.

Comment: Okay thanks guys ! I would have to look for different approach then !